# from JSON object to Java Script Object that contains js function name

Tags: json, scala, ecmascript-6

I have this JS object:

```
{ validator: myValidator }
```

myValidator is a java JAVASCRIPT function NAME that will be declared somewhere else. I am planning to use it like:

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='status' editable={ { validator: myValidator } }>Job Status</TableHeaderColumn>
```

where TableHeaderColumn  is a react component. So, the question is: What is the JSON string that after using JSON.parse or a similar command I will obtain the { validator: myValidator } object where  myValidator  is "the name of a function", not a string. This is not clear for me inclusive at the referenced solution.

Comment: What is your question? How to parse JSON in JavaScript?

Comment: No, this is not my question...

Comment: You would include the name of the function as string in the JSON and map the name to the actual function after you parsed the JSON by simply iterating over the object and look up the function by name a map that contains all validation functions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I was thinking there was a direct way to do this without the mapping.

Comment: Since JSON doesn't have a concept of functions, no.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a JS Object to JSON, you can use `json = JSON.stringify(jsObject)`

To convert JSON to a JS Object, just use `jsObject = JSON.parse(json)`

Comment: but... how could I represent  { validator: myValidator }  in JSON so, after parsing from JSON to JS I will get  { validator: myValidator }?. In this case myValidator is not a string, but the name of a function.